# Attempt to assign property "parent_id" on null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to save data into mySql table with these codes

*category.blade.php*

```
 <form name="categoryForm" id="categoryForm" action="{{url('admin/add-edit-category')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Select Category Level</label>
                <select name="parent_id" id="parent_id" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                    <option value="0">Main Category</option>
                </select>
            </div>

           <div class="card-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
    </form>
```

*CategoryController.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use App\Category;
use App\Section;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
public function addEditCategory(Request $request, $id = null)
{

    if ($id = "") {
        $title = "Add Category";
        // Add category functionality

        //if id is not get it will create a new 
        $category = new Category();
    } else {
        $title = "Edit Category";
        // Edit category functionality
    }

    //checking form data is comming or not?
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $data = $request->all();
        // echo "<pre>";
        // print_r($data);
        // die;


        $category->parent_id = $data['parent_id'];
       
        $category->save();
    }

    // Get All the Sections
    $getSections = Section::get();
    return view('admin.categories.add-edit-category')->with(compact('title', 'getSections'));
}
}
```

but when I push the submit button in the addEditCategory view give me the
Attempt to assign property "parent_id" on null
how can I solve this?

Comment: you need to add `parent_id` column on your `Category` Model's fillable property

Comment: Are you sure you mean `=` instead of `==`?

Comment: yes i already did it in the category seeder file by accesing all the data into the Category model's. 
Even i run 
if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $data = $request->all();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
         die;
}

it will print all the data but when push to database show the error

Comment: @tadman yes i want to save data not to equal

Comment: @MukhlisRaza tadman means your ```if``` statement: ```if ($id = "")```, that's right? Is that all of your controller's code, what line is throwing that error?

Comment: oh thanks so much, I didn't realize it

Comment: `=` is *assignment*, while `==` is *comparison*. The difference is only one character, but substantial in meaning.

Comment: @tadman yes you right thanks problem is resolved I did a mistake. unfortunately, I put a single = instead of double
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a mistake in **CategoryController.php**. Unfortunately, I put a single '=' instead of double '=='. checking the id is equal to empty or not.
Now Updated

**CategoryController.php**

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
public function addEditCategory(Request $request, $id = null)
{
   if ($id == "") {
       $title = "Add Category";
       // Add category functionality     
   } else {
      $title = "Edit Category";
      // Edit category functionality
   }
 
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
      
        $parent_id = $request->get("parent_id");

           $category = Category::updateOrCreate([
               "parent_id" => $parent_id 
           ], [
               "parent_id" => $parent_id 
           ]);
    }

    // Get All the Sections
    $getSections = Section::get();
    return view('admin.categories.add-edit-category')->with(compact('title', 'getSections'));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel => 5.3, please try this method

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use App\Category;
use App\Section;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
public function addEditCategory(Request $request, $id = null)
{

 
   if ($id = "") {
       $title = "Add Category";
       // Add category functionality

    
   } else {
      $title = "Edit Category";
      // Edit category functionality
   }
 
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
      
        $parent_id = $request->get("parent_id");

           $category = Category::updateOrCreate([
               "parent_id" => $parent_id 
           ], [
               "parent_id" => $parent_id 
           ]);
    }

    // Get All the Sections
    $getSections = Section::get();
    return view('admin.categories.add-edit-category')->with(compact('title', 'getSections'));
}
}
```